# Only show results from database if value equals original value

Tags: javascript, node.js, db2, ejs

I am displaying a staff page, where the owner can remove staff from editing their dashboard. However, because I am using one master table for all this in my DB, it shows everyone who has access to every account in the system. I only want to show the results to those who have access to their account. I was thinking that comparing it to the company name they are logged in with, vs the company names that are returned in the results.

like so:

```
my company name: xxx

results:
company name: xxx
company name: yyy
```

now, how do I only show company name: xxx?
I was thinking front-end script, not sure how to go about this. Thanks

front-end:

```
 <% if(data.length){ 
                    for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) { %>
              <tr>
                <td data-label="username"><%= data[i].USERNAME %></td>
                <td data-label="Company"><%= data[i].COMPANY %></td>
                <td data-label="First Name"><%= data[i].FN %><%=data[i].LN %></td>
```

backend:

```
 var showStaff = "select * from LOGIN";
ibmdb.open(ibmdbconnDash, function (err, conn) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  conn.query(showStaff, function (err, rows) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    //logging rows in the account page

    res.render("accountInfo", {
      data: rows,
      username,
      userName,
      FN: firstName,
      LN: lastName,
      CO: company,
      USERNAME: userName,
    });
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: @appleapple showed code. would front end script be best?

Comment: just remember even if you filter out in front-end, others can simply fake the request (if filter in query) or simply look into network response (if only filter in UI, which also take more data (bandwidth) to transmit).

Comment: in this case maybe you can simply add a `where` clause in backend? (I'm not familiar with `idmdb` but it should have something similar)

Comment: if you don't need to add access control, filter in frontend (UI) may save bandwidth depend on the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this line of code,

```
var showStaff = "select * from LOGIN";
```

Can't you modify this query to only show the rows where company name matches what you want?
Something like

```
var showStaff = "select * from LOGIN where COMPANY_NAME = 'xxx'";
```

Make sure you inject the name of the company into the query in a safe way, to avoid SQL injection exploits.